# Выводим определенную рубрику в записях

Tags: php

```
$popular_posts = new WP_Query( array(  'category__not_in' => $exclude_from_all_popular_posts, 'orderby' => 'comment_count', 'paged' => $paged ) );
```

Как правильно заменить, чтобы выводились не все рубрики, а только определенная рубрика, которая мне нужна?
Менял `category__not_in` безрезультатно.

Comment: Использовать `category__in` пробовали?

Comment: @DaemonHK да, пробовал, прописывал category__in=1. По идее должен был выводить только записи без категорий. А по итогу все равно все показывает.

Comment: Записи без категорий? С чего вы взяли? Он должен был вывести записи из категории с id=1... P.S. Или рубрика `без категории` и имеет ид=1? Я уже не помню)

Comment: @DaemonHK рубрика без категории=1.

Comment: Может лучше тогда использовать `get_posts()`? https://wp-kama.ru/function/get_posts

Comment: @DaemonHK уже решил данную проблему.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Самостоятельно решил данную проблему. `$exclude_from_all_popular_posts`заменяем на id постов и все заработает. 
Например: `$popular_posts = new WP_Query( array(  'category__not_in' => 1,59, 'orderby' => 'comment_count', 'paged' => $paged ) );`
Аналогично с `category__in` и т.д.

Comment: эм... а вы проверяли чему равен `$exclude_from_all_popular_posts`? Вы его раньше заполняли?